# An easy way to create a JQuery single field confirmation dialogs for a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is all I want to do:

- User click on an image button
- It displays a confirmation dialog with a label and a text field and OK button
- If they enter a value and click OK button then returns the value which can then be used to invoke a constructed hyperlink based on the value entered.
- If they click on cancel leave value blank then the popup is just dismissed

But the page is generated dynamically and there may be many rows that have an image button that will open the said popup, I dont want to have to add a javascript function for each popup required.

Im already using JQuery a little bit so I think using JQuery Dialog is the way to go but I'm not getting anywhere with actually implementing this seemingly simple task.

I'm looking for a simple example without any extraneous cruft that I dont actually need.

**Update With More detail**

This is what I currently have in the calling htmnl

There are two buttons within a  element, the first is an input button is fine, the second is currently just invokes a hyperlink  but it needs a value for the discogsid parameter (currently xxxxx). So I want clicking on the second one to provide user with a way to enter a value and then if they enter something use that as the value of discogsid in the url

```
 <td>
    <input title="View tracks in this release" onclick="return toggleMe(this,'232')" 
src="/images/open.png" alt="Open" type="image">&nbsp;
    <a href="/linkrelease/?discogsid=xxxxxx&amp;mbid=e3c0e7c7-df7c-4b51-9894-e45d1480e7b5" target="_blank">
<img src="/images/link.png"</a>
    </td>
```

Comment: What do you have so far? Do you have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or anything we can look at? It will help us understand your difficulties and help us point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Danny Not really Ive been trying to understand the Jquery examples without much luck so far, the crux of the question is simply how do you create a single textfield dialog - that would be a good start that I could work with.

Comment: lots of modal/dialog plugins you can use for this. They will provide event API's for things like `open` and `close`. You then just need to store within a click handler the image that was clicked and change the url when modal `close` event is triggered.

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/vvjj8/6511/

Comment: simple demo changing text rather than images  http://plnkr.co/edit/22xlT8ObyM3e7qMW5G92?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My difficulty with both of these solutions was actually get the dialog to be invoked from the html. both solutions used  that didn't compatible with my situation.

I worked out that as in the solutions the hyperlink was not actually a hyperlink that if I changed it to a button like I do for the first option things would be easier, so the hmtl changed to

```
<td>
<input title="View tracks in this release" onclick="return toggleMe(this,'30')" src="/images/open.png" alt="Open" type="image">
&nbsp;
<input title="Link" onclick="return promptForDiscogsReleaseId(this,'676fdad7-69b5-4f38-a547-a8320f01ad59')" src="/images/custom_link.png" alt="Link" type="image">
</td>

and added this javascript function that shows a prompt and then creates a new page with the derived hyperlink
```

javascript function to

```
function promptForDiscogsReleaseId(btn,mbReleaseId) {

    var answer = prompt("Please the Discogs Release Id you want to link this release to:");
    window.open("/linkrelease/?discogsid="+answer+"&mbid="+mbReleaseId, "_blank");
}
```

and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple :)
try this http://jsfiddle.net/7r1z8v7u/

```
$("div").click(function() {

    var answer = prompt("Pls provide your input");
    if(answer != null) myHyperlinkBuilder(answer);
}
```

Here I have used "div" as selector. Through this, in one shot, we can handle click behavior for all the images.

After that, it is simple JavaScript to display dialog box. Only when the user has enter some input, through if condition we proceed with building our custom URL.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @jsaddict so prompt is just html ?, that might just do for my scenario, trying it out now

Comment: @js addict Ive just updated my question with more details as the prompt looks good but I don; think I can use a div in my circumstance

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you will need to attach an on click event to your link. You can do this in any way you deem acceptable for your application. I'll use a class in my example.

```
<a href="http://..." class="requireQueryEntry" target="_blank">Test</a>

$('.requireQueryEntry').click(GetSearchQuery);
```

Your click handler will need to prevent the default action since you are using a link. Which means you'll have to reissue your navigation in your code.

```
function GetSearchQuery() {
    var thelink = $(this);
    $("#dialogSearch").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "Search",
        height: 180,
        width: 340,
        buttons: {
            "Search": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                callback(thelink);
            },
                "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
    //This line prevents the default action and the propagation of the event. It only works this way because jQuery handles it that way for us.
    return false;
}


function callback(theLink) {
    var href = theLink.attr("href");
    var target = theLink.attr('target');
    var newQuery = $("#googleQuery").val();
    if (newQuery.length > 0) {
        href = href.replace("xxxxxx", newQuery);
    } else {
        return; // end the function here when the user enters nothing
    }
    //This may cause popup blockers
    var win = window.open(href, target);
    $("#googleQuery").val("");
}
```

I've put together an example: http://jsfiddle.net/anh7g8eb/2/

Comment: Thankyou, I have tried implementing in my code and it had no effect, no popup was display and the hyperlink still works. I think my problem is the line -  $('.requireQueryEntry').click(GetSearchQuery); in your jsfiddle that was within javascript but not within any function which I dont understand but tried to do in my code by just adding to my javascript file but maybe that is wrong ?

Comment: Ive realised another problem is your GetSearchQuery() refers to another class #dialogSearch but I dont have such a class

Comment: Hmm, it s seems that you need this  div in your jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/anh7g8eb/3/ because making minor change prevents popup but I dont see how this fits in with what I want